# Filtering what get puts oin an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, magento, sorting, magento-1.7

im doing some work with the Magento SOAP API and i am trying to create a valid list of orders. I have got the list but it shows both the configurable products as well as simple product giving me duplicating like the image below:
[image: item list]

The first listing of the same product is the configurable product, the second is the simple product. What i need to do is filter out the simple products so they dont shown in the list or get stored. This sounds simple but there is one problem that im struggling to get my head around how to solve, and that is products like the Nokia in the image above are standard simple products and have no configurable properties and they also need to be shown!

So basically i need to get rid of the simple products relating to the configurable products but none others.

Here is my loop and array push:

```
foreach($sales_order_info->items as $i){
                $nextItem = new item();
                $nextItem->set_order_id($i->order_id);
                $nextItem->set_sku($i->sku);
                $nextItem->set_name($i->name);
                $nextItem->set_qty_ordered($i->qty_ordered);
                $nextItem->set_price($i->price);
                $nextItem->set_row_total($i->row_total);

                array_push($this->items, $nextItem);
            }
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to filter simple product of a configurable product:

```
 if ($product->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE) {              
    if ( $product->getParentItemId()) {
                        $parent_product_type = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($product->getParentItemId())->getProductType();
                        //if Parent product type is configurable don't output its simple product
                        if ($parent_product_type == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
                            continue; 
                        }
                    }
}
```

If you don't want to extend Magento API and write your own custom calls you can try the following.

The second option is to try using (not sure how you load it, with what Call):

```
$i->type
```

and then filter the array with PHP (i.e. if there are 2 elements with the same name and quantity remove the one that has type==simple)

Or the third option would be (if you don't have any free products) just check if price is equal to zero, as simple products which belong to configurable has price = 0.0000

```
if ($i->price==0.0000) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: This looks like what i need, but by the looks of it you have written the code as if you were modifying magento itself. Could you show me how to do this using the SOAP api calls? thanks

Comment: updated my answer with possible solutions, although I would prefer to write my own extension with custom calls

Comment: Thanks Sergei! i understand what your saying now and i get how your telling me to implement it. Im struggling to work out what the best method is to filter the array.. could you guide me a little on how to do it? thanks

Comment: Sorry I think you better ask another question as this would be more PHP related (and not Magento) stuff and I don't know any PHP function that can do this out of the box